# PHP Undefined Variable & Class name must e a valid object or a string

Tags: php, class, variables, object, undefined

trailblazer here.  I'm in the midst of teaching myself php and sql.  Currently I'm working on an application and using this tutorial video as a template:

https://youtu.be/tPspjWX8GXw?t=15m24s

For the sake of time I started it around where I'm having a problem.  [I've included an image stating the issue in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTjzn.png)  Currently I am working to resolve it, but I do not know enough about PHP yet to know how to fix it.  The line (potentially lines by the time I'm done with this) in question is:

```
    $serialArray = $serialModelCode->GetSerialByName($name);
```

By my understanding, I should be creating a variable called 'serialArray', passing it to a new object (serialModelCode).  Then this should be passed to another file's parameters: GetSerialByName($name);

However nothing seems to be working properly.  Below I've included all of my code.  If someone can help me figure out my issue and understand what is going on that would be appreciative.  Also if there is a flaw in my logic above please let me know.

- Trailblazer

  require ("Model/SerialModel.php");
   class SerialController
    {

  function CreateSerialDropdownList()

  {
      $serialModelCode = new $SerialModel();

  ```
  /*
   * Creates a drop down list
   * Takes the Serial Types and puts them into an array
   */
  $result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
              Please select an Item: 
              <select name = 'names' >
                  <option value = '%' >All</option>
                  " . $this->CreateOptionValues($serialModelCode->GetSerialNames()) .
              "</select>
              <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search' />
              </form>";

  return $result;
  ```

  }
   function CreateOptionValues(array $valueArray)
   {
      $result = "";

  ```
  foreach ($valueArray as $value) {
      $result = $result . "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
  }

  return $result;
  ```

  }
  function CreateSerialTables ($names)
  {

  ```
  $serialModelCode = new $SerialModel();
  $serialArray = $serialModelCode->GetSerialByName($name);
  $result = "";

  /*
   * Generates a serialTable for each Serial Entity in the array
   */
  foreach ($serialArray as $key => $serial) 
  {
      $result = $result .
              /*
               * Will need to change coffeeTable to serialTable
               * at some point.  Not right now though
               */
              "<table class = 'coffeeTable'>
                  <tr>
                      <th rowspan='6' width = '150px' ><img runat = 'server' src = '$serial->image' /></th>
                      <th width = '75px' >Name: </th>
                      <td>$serial->name</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <th>Type: </th>
                      <td>$serial->type</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <th>Price: </th>
                      <td>$serial->price</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <th>Serial Number: </th>
                      <td>$serial->serialNum</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td colspan='2' >$coffee->desc</td>
                  </tr>                      
               </table>";
  }        
  return $result;}}?>
  ```

edit: apparently there is something wrong with my formatting.  Oi vey.  I've fixed a lot of it, but some of the space doesn't want to cooperate properly.

Answer (score 0):

"$serialArray = $serialModelCode->GetSerialByName($name);"

You have a class serialModelCode which has a member/function GetSerialByName which takes one argument as input ($name). This function then performs some needful action whatever is written in GetSerialByName  and returns an object or an array. I assume array as the sample code which you have shared for other functions returns array(drop down html). You can create the $serialArray before the call like below $serialArray =array(); 
or else the line is good enough to create the array for you.
"$serialArray = $serialModelCode->GetSerialByName($name);"

You must be creating $name varibale as you are passing this as input to the function. If this is null or incorrect or not defined then php will complain about it.

Your question is not that clear regarding this particular line but if it is related about how to understand this statement then it means the point I mentioned above. $serialArray is holding the final output returned by class function $serialModelCode->GetSerialByName($name) and that final object you have to take further for any needful processing. Sorry If I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

What is this `new $SerialModel()` How $ camehere.